# If the empty set is a subset of every set, why isn't $\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}=\{\{a\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

If the empty set is a subset of every set, why it isn't written with the elements of a set? like so $\{1,2,3,\emptyset\}$

Or why isn't $\{\emptyset,\{a\}\}=\{\{a\}\}$? I know one has two elements and the other has 1 but since the empty set is a subset of both, then why it isn't being mentioned explicitly in the definition of the set?

Comment: The empty set is a **subset** of every set. Not an **element** of every set. Recall the definition of subset and you will see why this is so.

Comment: "Subset of" is not the same as "member of."

Comment: Why isn't $\{\{a\}\}=\{a\}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews are they the same?

Comment: No, @kuhaku: $\{a\} \in \{\{a\}\}$, but $\{a\}\neq \{\{a\}\}$.

Comment: $\{\{a\}\}$ is the set with one element: $\{a\}$, an element which happens also to be a set. Be careful though: Note that $a\notin \{\{a\}\}$. What we do have is that $a\in \{a\},$ but  $a \notin \{\{a\}\}$.

Comment: No, I was arguing by analogy. $\{\emptyset\}$ is not equal to $\emptyset$ in the same way that $\{\{a\}\}$ is not equal to $\{a\}$. @kuhaku

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The empty set is a *subset* of every set, but it is not an element of every set.

In your examples, $$\varnothing \in \{\varnothing, \{a\}\}\text{ but } \varnothing \notin \{\{a\}\},$$

but it is a *subset* of both sets:

$$\varnothing \subset \{\varnothing, \{a\}\}, \text{ and } \varnothing \subset \{\{a\}\}.$$

Answer (score 3):

What happens if $\varnothing$ is in fact an element of some set? For example, $\{\varnothing\}$?

How can you tell the difference between $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$, if you add the empty set as an element to *every* set?

Membership and inclusion are two different relations, and should be treated differently.