# Why isn't $\{\{\emptyset\}\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If the set $ \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ has just one element that is $\{\emptyset\}$ and is empty otherwise, shouldn't it be equivalent to $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Comment: "If the set {Ф,{Ф}} has just one element": it doesn't

Comment: @Gregory J. Puleo, so its cardinality is 2 then?

Comment: $1 \neq \{ n\in\mathbb{N} : n^2=n\} = \{1\}$ but $1 \in \{1\}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is belonging not transitive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3355751/why-is-belonging-not-transitive)

Comment: The set $\{ \Phi,\{\Phi\}\}$ contains two elements, namely $\Phi$ and $\{\Phi\}$, while the set $\{\{\Phi\}\}$ contains one single element, $\{\Phi\}$.

Comment: @hal4math: and $0$?

Comment: I live in a world were $0 \in \mathbb{N}_{0}$ but $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$ :).

Comment: And refer for that to [Peano. Original work](https://archive.org/details/arithmeticespri00peangoog/page/n22).

Comment: Technically a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107771/if-the-empty-set-is-a-subset-of-every-set-why-isnt-emptyset-a-a), but this case might be more confusing. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286066/the-meaning-of-singleton-and-existence-of-varnothing-varnothing) is also related (and is linked to a few questions itself).

Comment: @hal4math Excluding the cardinality of the empty set and the additive identity from $\mathbb{N}$? That sounds like an ugly world :)

Comment: @hal4math Not to mention the zeroth power in the binomial theorem or in a general power series.

Comment: @user76284 Well, the set of continuous function from the reals into reals which are differentiable at at least one point, is a meager set in the space of continuous function. So, not sure how much "uglier" everything gets here, especially in light of me just adding one subscript to a symbol to magically get all the things you mentioned. :)

Comment: @user76284 I of course get you. I just learned it differently in the beginning, actually the first proper thing I learned in math. So emotionally it stayed with me. :)

Answer (score 16):

Assuming your "$\Phi$" is the empty set $\{\}$ (usually denoted "$\emptyset$," LaTeX code "\$\emptyset\$"), the important point is that $\emptyset$ **is not nothing**. It *contains* nothing, but that's not the same thing, any more than an empty bag is the same as no bag at all.

*It's important to say at this point that you shouldn't push the bag metaphor too far, but in some contexts - including this one - I think it is useful.*

In particular, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ has **two** elements - we can't ignore the by-itself $\emptyset$. After all, if we could the whole thing would evaporate: highlighting in red the bits that we erase at each step we'd get $$\mbox{$\{\color{red}{\emptyset},\{\color{red}{\emptyset}\}\}=\{\color{red}{\{\}}\}=\color{red}{\{\}}=\quad$ .}$$ I'm not even sure what that last thing is!

It's worth mentioning at this point that the usual framework of set theory builds *everything* up from the emptyset alone. So far from being a silly hair-splitting, caution around the emptyset is quite serious mathematics.

Comment: This question seems to come up in some form or another quite often, and the bag analogy is by far the best explanation for this that I have seen. Massive +1 from me.

Comment: I have used the bag analogy myself. It really helps describing the diffference between $\varnothing$ and $\{\varnothing\}$ and so on.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy: I don't see how anyone can successfully teach basic set theory without using an analogy to bags or containers of some kind. But this is the first time I have seen **evaporating** bags! =)

Comment: Just for the record, I have edited the post to write the sets with MathJax, making the same assumption as in the first sentence of this answer.